# In streaming,where does demuxing take place ? at server side or client side?

Tags: http, networking, streaming, rtsp

see if i have one media file like .mkv or .mp3 now i am playing it on my computer by using streaming. Now i want to ask you **when data comes from server to client at that time who is going to do demuxing?**

```
Does at server side any demuxer program open file & give frames & then
streaming application make packet of that demuxed frame and then transmit 
it to client ?
```

or

```
At server side streaming application just read any media file in chunks of some
bytes & transmit to client then client side one demuxer program parse that & find
 real frames from that and play?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely later, I'm not sure why would server do any sort of work regarding understanding of data it sends. It would just burn cpu cycles on server, and I can't see any benefit of doing that.